# Can I pull from private images Docker hub free private repo?

Tags: docker

I am trying to pull my private images from Docker hub free private repo.
Here is what I have done.

1. Verify that `myrepo/myimage` exists in Docker Hub as private image.
2. Run the following

`$ docker login docker.io -u myusername`

Password:

```
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/sha/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
```

`$ docker push myusername/xxx-test:latest`

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/myusername/xxx-test]
e836ed963202: Pushed
24769bc5b044: Pushed
75b121557396: Pushed
4075573f4aa9: Pushed
fa6f238ab393: Mounted from myusername/multi-worker
d6100d978ba2: Mounted from myusername/multi-worker
88b43919be61: Mounted from myusername/multi-worker
0fcbbeeeb0d7: Mounted from myusername/multi-worker
latest: digest: sha256:985d3ed5e09915d5c84431243d511798ac4219a69ca3e73c6514dcb903b32853 size: 1990
```

`$ docker pull myusername/xxx-test:latest`

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myusername/xxx-test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Howver, Docker hub showed it had been pulled.
[image]

I have searched SO and googled on the same topic and tried all their suggestions. Nothing worked so far. It will work only if I go to the image settings an make it public.

Any input?

**Update**
Following the login command I immediately did a push, which was successful.
Then immediately did a pull for the same image, which failed.

Comment: More than likely you didn't login, didn't type the image name correctly, or don't have access to the repo from your user. I'm not sure how we can help debug that when all of those components are private and masked from your question.

Comment: I believe the pulled count on the web interface includes pulls from the web interface itself. I'll see pulls of new images happen within seconds of pushing the image and viewing on the web page without doing a pull.

Comment: I have verified that I did not mistype anything. The login return messages says `Login succeeded`

Comment: Challenge is that we cannot verify that, and the error message is suggesting you didn't type everything correctly. From the same prompt after the login, can you push an image to that repo and then see it in the web?

Comment: @BMitch, I updated the post. 1) login = success, 2) push an image = success, 3) pull the same image = access denied. All in the same session sequentially.

Comment: @Shawn Just in case: have you tried to login just before the pull?

Comment: @emi, to be clean, I logout before login. So the sequence is like this: logout -> Login -> push a new image (success) -> pull the same image (failure)

Comment: I understand. But in case, to narrow down the problem: it could be with the second `docker` command executed after `login`, or it could be specifically with the `pull` command.